# How can instantiate the type in java

Tags: java

```
package crawler;

import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;

class Crawler{

    public static void main(String args[]){

    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();     // **HERE!!!!!!!!!**

    GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod("http://www.google.com");

    int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(getMethod);

    System.out.println("response=" + getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());;

    getMethod.releaseConnection();

    }

}
```

The HttpClient from Apache Httpclient.

the code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public interface HttpClient
```

how can fix the problem "`HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();` "?
THANKS!

Comment: you just can't create an object like that, that is an interface, use anonymous or find a class that implements that interface and create an instance of that

Comment: That's an interface. With a quick google query I've found an example of how to use HttpClient correctly: https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/. Remember: always google your problem before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClient`  is an interface. YTou can't do that.

Correct way is

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an interface. You have to either implement it or create an anonymous class(which is still implement)